# SAS Arrays - Create maximum value per month

Tags: arrays, sas

I need to use a SAS array to create the maximum value for each month to establish which program took the longest to run.

The data would be:

```
 Month  Value   Program
  Jan     8      A
  Jan     6      B
  Feb     2      C
  Feb     1      A
  Mar     9      C
  Mar     6      B
```

And so on.

Can anyone tell me the syntax to use

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use arrays...I would sort the data, then use First. notation.

```
Proc sort data=data;
 by month descending value;
run;

Data longest;
 set data;
 by month descending value;
 if first.month then output;
run;
```

This will give you a record for each month with the highest value.

**Update:**

The strength of arrays is processing variables in one observation. You can retain arrays, but a Hash object would be more appropriate for checking variables across observations, if your data is too big to sort, then process with a data step.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helps and was the way I coded the answer this morning. My manager asked me to think how this could be done using an array to improve my sas training.

Answer (score 0):

As Carolina mentioned, arrays are used to read across variables in the same observation.  They are not suitable for achieving your task here.
A simple PROC SUMMARY is probably the easiest way to achieve this.  I assume that your real data for the time taken to run is recorded to fractions of seconds and therefore is virtually impossible to have 2 programs run for exactly the same time in a month.  If not then you will need to consider what to do in the event of a tie (proc sql would be the better approach there).

Here is the code, if you only want to see the program with the highest value, not the value itself, then remove 'value' in the brackets with 'program'.

```
    data have;
    input month $ value program $;
    cards;
      Jan     8      A
      Jan     6      B
      Feb     2      C
      Feb     1      A
      Mar     9      C
      Mar     6      B
    ;
    run;

    proc summary data=have nway;
    class month;
    output out=want (drop=_:) maxid(value(program value))=;
    run;
```